# Finding number of occurance of an element in a list

Tags: java, list

Is there a direct way to find out if the list contains duplicates? 
Direct API method in some third party utils?
And if the list contains duplicates how many such duplicate elements exist in the list?
Code we can write but I want to know if any direct API exists?

Comment: [This is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist) that might help.

Comment: Are you trying to see if there are references to the same object, or if there are multiple instances of a class within a container?

Comment: Actually this list is of Strings. List contains name of methods. I want to know check if particular method is overloaded in the class. I am getting all the methods through reflection and putting in a list. And now passing the methodName for which i need to verify. But if this list contains more than one , then I need to maintain a counter. I can do that but I want to know if any better apporach so i asked if there is any direct API.

Comment: Ah...  Well, I believe reflextion can tell you if a method is Overriden...  use just use the getAnnotations method and check them against the Override java Annotation.

Comment: Nice idea Mirrored but its a third pary jar/classes and we are not sure if they have used annotations for override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an API you can find duplicates with [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

Just add your list do the set and use the [count](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 4):

You can count occurrences with

```
List<T> list =
Map<T, Integer> count = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
for(T t: list) {
   Integer i = count.get(t);
   if (i ==  null) i = 0;
   count.put(t, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you'll have to do it by yourself. But you can use objects that won't allow to insert duplicate data ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268672/is-there-a-no-duplicate-list-implementation-out-there))

Comment: Well I want to allow duplicates in the list. It will have duplicates but want to know if has duplicates then how many?

Comment: Then you need to implement it as there is no existing API to do that, but there are a lot of example of how to do that on the Internet (like in Sorrow comment)

Comment: What do you mean with no ? There are in fact third party utils that can count duplicates in collections that allow them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
public int getNumOfElementInList(List<Object> myList, Object myElement){
   int count = 0;
   for(Object element: myList){
      if(element.equals(myElement)) //or use instanceof instead, depending
         count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

This will give you the number of an element in a list.  Alternatively, you could make a List instead of using count, and add the duplicate elements to the List, and return that.

Such as:

```
public List<DuplicateStats> getTotalNumOfElementInList(List<Object> myList){
   List<DuplicateStats> dups = new ArrayList<DuplicateStats>();
   int i;
   for(Object element: myList){
      if((i = dups.indexOf(element) != -1)
         dups.get(i).addOne();
      else
         List.add(new DuplicateStats(element));
   }
   return count;
}

public class DuplicateStats {
   private Object element;
   private int count;

   public DuplicateStats(Object o){
        element = o;
   }

   public boolean equals(String compare){
        return element.toString.equals(compare);
   }

   public void addOne(){
       count++;
   }
}
```

You can add getters, setters, etc. to the class DuplicateStats, but it will keep track of duplicates for you.

Comment: Well fine. But complexity is O(n2)

Comment: This is easily modifiable if you want to get the number of all duplicates in a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out how many duplicates there are you could keep the list with duplicates, together with a set without duplicates.  The number of duplicates is then just the size of the list minus the size of the set.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in methods to do this. However you can use LinkedHashSet for example to solve this problem. It does not allow duplicates (as it acts like a set) but it preserves an order of elements (as it acts like a list). You can iterate over all of elements from your list and add them to LinkedHashSet, checking if add method returns true or false.

Comment: Thanks but I want to allow duplicates.