# JAVA collections, no duplicates

Tags: java, collections

I want to discuss a question about java collection framework. Here is the question:

You need to store elements in a collection that guarantees that no duplicates are stored. Which one of the following interfaces provide that capability?

a.java.util.List

b.java.util.Collection

c.java.util.Map

d.none of the above

It is pretty clear that the first two options are incorrect, but which one is true c. or d. and why?
Personally, my answer is d.none of the above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List without duplicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961327/list-without-duplicates)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961327/list-without-duplicates

Comment: @bigGuy But he said no duplicates in the title ;)

Comment: a `Set` is a `Collection`.

Comment: @bigGuy This question/answer only shows that there is a implementation of List, but the interface itself does not forbid duplicates.

Comment: A Map cannot contain duplicate key elements, but it can contain duplicate value elements. Further more a Map contains Entities not elements!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Map does not allow duplicate keys of course but allows duplicate values. So I think the answer would be `d)`. The collection that does not allow any duplicates is `Set`. An example with `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("str1");
    set.add("str2");
    set.add("str3");
    set.add("str4");
    set.add("str1");
    System.out.println(set); // ["str1", "str2", "str3". "str4"] "str1" is added only once
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the same way I am thinking.

Comment: `HashSet` avoids duplicates only if the `hashCode()` of the objects stored are different. It doesn't guarantee to avoid duplicates if the fields of a complex object used in `hashCode()` and `equals()` function are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces provide no capabilities at all. So, d)

Answer (score 1):

Set does not allow duplicates, Map will have unique key but can have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be C:

Take a look at the [Map javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

so with something like this you can achieve the no duplicates requirement (Which is basically the implementation of HashSet):

```
String testString = "foo";
Map<String, String> map;
map.put(testString, testString);
```

Comment: I agree with it, but I am still for d.

Comment: @nenito Maybe some links to convince you ;) [Link1](http://www.careerride.com/view-answer.aspx?Id=6&type=Java-6), [Link2](http://www.astiwz.com/online-exam/quiz-objective-general-knowledge/quiz/Objects-and-Collections/General-Questions/Java-Programming) Q4, [Link3](https://www.facebook.com/CoreJavaQuiz/posts/280043322131440), [Link4](http://www.withoutbook.com/online_test.php?quiz=2&quesNo=150&subject=Top%20150%20Core%20Java%20Online%20Practice%20Test%20|%20Multiple%20Choice) Q13

Comment: Probably this question is taken from one of this places, but still I can't change my mind. A Map allows duplicate values. The value is a part of key-value pair (entity), a element.

Answer (score 0):

A `java.util.Map` cannot contain duplicate keys.

Refer this [Documetation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Get more details with example on this [Example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html)

Comment: A Map cannot contain duplicate key elements, but it can contain duplicate value elements. Further more a Map contains Entities not elements!