# How to incorporate a boolean in a method JAVA

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I having a hard time getting the right output because i dont know how boolean exactly works inside a method. I have an arraylist and I'm check for any duplicates in the arraylist Here's my code

```
public void rentOneInstrument(List<Instrument> instrumentList){
        String a="";
        String b="";
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < instrumentList.size(); j++) {
                a ="";
                a = instrumentList.get(j).getName();

                for (int i = j+1; i < instrumentList.size(); i++) {
                    b = instrumentList.get(i).getName();
                    System.out.println("a" + a + " b" + b);
                    if(a.equals(b)){
                        found = true;
                    }else {
                        found = false;
                    }
                }
        }
        if (found) {
            System.out.println("duplicate");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no duplicate");
        }
    }
```

Here is my output

```
a Cymbals b Drums,..
a Cymbals b Cello,..
a Cymbals b Cymbals,..
a Drums b Cello,..
a Drums b Cymbals,..
a Cello b Cymbals
```

no duplicate  // prints no duplicate when there is clearly a duplicate in the output. How can i correct this?

Edit.. Btw I just a want a single out put that prints whether it found a duplicate or not inside the loop

Comment: See [Prevent duplicate entries in arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192532/how-to-prevent-the-adding-of-duplicate-objects-to-an-arraylist): consider using a `set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(a.equals(b)){
  found = true
}else {
    found = false;
}
```

This is your problem. This way only the last iteration of your loop will be stored in `found`. Since you are initializing it as `false` you don't need to set it to that again here.

```
   for (int i = j+1; i < instrumentList.size(); i++) {
      b = instrumentList.get(i).getName();
      System.out.println("temp1 " + a + " temp2 " + b);
      if(a.equals(b)){
         found = true;
      }
   }
```

Alternatively, you can use a `break` statement when you have found a match to get out of the loop like so:

```
if(a.equals(b)){
  found = true;
  break;
}else {
    found = false;
}
```

This way, `found` will be true and no other iterations will be performed, continuing after the end of the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following input :

```
a,b,c,a,d
```

Now whit your code it would be false as d is not repeated. It would over right the value for a that is repeated. Also once a element is fond that it is replanted you don't need to go through the entire loop of all elements hence there is a break.

```
public void rentOneInstrument(List<Instrument> instrumentList){
        String a="";
        String b="";
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < instrumentList.size(); j++) {
                a ="";
                a = instrumentList.get(j).getName();
                if(found) { break; } // Changed line here 
                for (int i = j+1; i < instrumentList.size(); i++) {
                    b = instrumentList.get(i).getName();
                    System.out.println("temp1 " + a + " temp2 " + b);
                    if(a.equals(b)){
                        found = true;
                        break; // Changed line here 
                    }
                }
        }
        if (found) {
            System.out.println("duplicate");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no duplicate");
        }
    }
```

Another way of doing it without a break would be

```
public void rentOneInstrument(List<Instrument> instrumentList){
        String a="";
        String b="";
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < instrumentList.size() && !found; j++) {
                a ="";
                a = instrumentList.get(j).getName();

                for (int i = j+1; i < instrumentList.size() && !found; i++) { // Changed for condition to look at the found variable too.
                    b = instrumentList.get(i).getName();
                    System.out.println("temp1 " + a + " temp2 " + b);
                    if(a.equals(b)){
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
        }
        if (found) {
            System.out.println("duplicate");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no duplicate");
        }
    }
```

A much better way of doing this would be using sets that doesn't contain duplicates.

```
public void rentOneInstrument(List<Instrument> instrumentList){
     Set< Instrument > instrumentSet = new HashSet< Instrument >(instrumentList);
     if(instrumentList.size()== instrumentSet.size()) {
          System.out.println("no duplicate");
     } else {
          System.out.println("duplicate");
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that just putting out code without any explanation whatsoever is wrong will help to understand what is going on?

Comment: hi. if i insert it inside the for- loop if prints after every ouput. What i want to do is to print a single output if there is a duplicate in the entire list

Comment: @Onedaynerd Please check the code and understand what has changed. It should not be change you printing everytime.

Comment: @Onedaynerd check the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let `found` be `false` by default. and just set it `true` if any duplicate is found.

```
 if(a.equals(b)){
      found = true;
 }else {
      // found = false;
      // don't do this otherwise it will override previous `found` value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rentOneInstrument(List<Instrument> instrumentList){

    boolean found=false;
    List<String> listString=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Instrument inst: instrumentList){
        if(listString.contains(inst.getName())){

            found=true;
        }
        else{
            listString.add(inst.getName());
        }


    }

  if (found) {
            System.out.println("duplicate");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no duplicate");
        }


}
```