# Need to check the paramater of an object in a list using java( list can have duplicate values as well)

Tags: java

I have an **Employee class**. It has three paramaters like **name(String), age(int),address(String)**
I have added **10 Employee objects into an ArrayList**
now i have a list of names but in it, name can be partial or complete.
I need to check whether any name in the above list exist in the list of emplyee object either partially or complete match.

Basiclly, I need to check contains for the name string parameter of emplyee object in the ArrayList.

What will be the best approach for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent the adding of duplicate objects to an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192532/how-to-prevent-the-adding-of-duplicate-objects-to-an-arraylist)

Comment: iterate one by one using for(item:list) approach.

Comment: I need to check contains whether added object's name parameter string contains the partial/complete name from the list

Comment: Tihis is the right approach: write the code. If having problems writing it, ask a question showing the code, where you are stuck, etc. If you succeed in writing the code, but you have questions about whether it follows best practices or has performance issues, then you can go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was not aware about the shared link next time, i will follow it from next time thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override arrayList class like this :

```
public class PartialStringList extends ArrayList<String>
{
 public boolean contains(Object o)
 {
    if(!(o instanceof String))
    {
        return false;
    }
    String s = (String)o;
    Iterator<String> iter = iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String iStr = iter.next();
        if (iStr.contain(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Java-8**
Then filter your list name :

```
List<String> employeNameList=new PartialNameList<>(nameList);
employeList=employeList.stream().
   filter(e->employeNameList.contains(e.getName()).
   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Java-7**

```
List<String> employeNameList=new PartialNameList<>(nameList);
List<Employe> filteredList=new ArrayList<>();
for(Employe e: employeList){
   if(employeNameList.contains(e.getName()){
    filteredList.add(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain it without Functional Interfaces and Lambda Expressions

Comment: @mayankagrawal if it works, click on this gray tick below the answer score.

Comment: I will do that but first need to test it and i am using java 7 so i can not use Functional Interfaces and Lambda Expressions

Comment: I was checking this out but in case of **Iterator<String> iter = iterator();** it's showing empty list but i have added the list into it

Comment: class PartialStringList extends ArrayList<String>
{
static List<String> nameList=new ArrayList<>();
    public PartialStringList(List<String> nameList) {
        PartialStringList.nameList=nameList;
    }

 public boolean contains(Object o)
 {
    if(!(o instanceof String))
    {
        return false;
    }
    String s = (String)o;
    Iterator<String> iter = iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String iStr = iter.next();
        if (iStr.contains(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Comment: Thank you. it's working fine for  me