# Search for a list of elements in a list which contains lists

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, linked-list

I have a set of elements {1,2,3},{2,3,4},{1,2,4},{7,8},{3,4,7,9},{12,16,18,19}, {1,2,4}.

I need to have a data structure which contains the list above appeared only once. If any new list appears and if it matches any of the existing list then I don't want that to be added to the resulting data structure.

For the above example the expected result should be :
{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{1,2,4},{7,8},{3,4,7,9},{12,16,18,19}.

One solution which I am having is to use Trees.
For ex: {1,2,3},{1,2,4}
       In the above list I will branch out for value 3 of 1st list and value 4 of 2nd list from the node which has value 2. In this way I can trace the list from the root and find whether the list appears or not.

```
     Root
      |
      |
      1
      |
      |
------2------
|            |
|            |
3            4
```

Please suggest if is there any algorithm to make it faster and in a simple way using C.

Comment: Classic Graph! Does the order matter ? Directed graph

Comment: In this way you have to create a tree, for every list beginning with new number...Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268672/is-there-a-no-duplicate-list-implementation-out-there

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using graph data structure.

To do so in c, you can use either of the following methods :

1. **Adjacency Matrix**

In this method, you need to maintain a matrix of relationship between your numbers, check out the below image :

[image: Adjacency Matrix]

2. **Linked list** :

In this method, you will maintain a list of connections, i.e if 2 has a connection to 1,3,4 then a list of 1,3,4 will be made with a head value of : 2

[image]

*These images are taken from : http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in .
And you can find great explaination and example code on the same site at : http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2013/09/graphs.html link*

Hope it helps.