# Java Collection implementation with these characteristics?

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to have a Java [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Collection.html) with the following characteristics:

1. No duplicates allowed (like [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html))
2. A predictable iteration order (like [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), or [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html))
3. Ability to "insert" new elements (like [List.add(index,element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-))
4. Ability to retrieve elements by index (like [List.get(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-))

Is there anything already out there with these characteristics?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268672/is-there-a-no-duplicate-list-implementation-out-there

Comment: @TylerKindy, yes, but the most recent answer there is 6 years old. Java has changed a bit since then.

Comment: @Johnathan M fair point. I'm unaware of any better solution today than ones provided in that question.

Comment: In fairness, the answer to that question still holds valid for this one.  'Is there anything out there', 'yes, apache commons-collections4's `SetUniqueList`'.  Or by 'out there' are you looking for 'part of the JDK'?  In which case, no.  Although `CopyOnWriteArraySet` uses a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` internally (in my JDK at least) so provides all the functionality, if you don't mind...  messing around...  to get access to the internal `List` for points 3 and 4.

Comment: @BeUndead, yeah, I don't mind DIY'ing this. Just wanted to know if something already existed. In the JDK would have been great. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

couldn't find anything in the documentation but why not just build one?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SetList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if(this.contains(e)) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            super.add(e);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

with this in main:

```
SetList<Integer> listLikeSet = new SetList<Integer>();
System.out.println(listLikeSet.add(1));
System.out.println(listLikeSet.add(2));
System.out.println(listLikeSet.add(1));
System.out.println(listLikeSet);
```

it outputs:

```
true
true
false
[1, 2]
```

Comment: What about the `addAll` method?  What about the `add` method of `ListIterator`? What about the `add` method of [subLists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,int%29)?

Comment: "...why not just build one?" Yes, if needed, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.